# Convert markdown links from inline to reference

Tags: regex, markdown

I have a changelog file formatted using [Github's markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

Initially I used *inline* links for every link I needed to add, that is:

```
This is some [example](http://www.stackoverflow.com) line of text.
```

Over time, as the file grew in size, it became a bit messy due mainly to this way of inserting links.

I'd like to convert all links from *inline*  to *reference* (see [description of each](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)), that is convert the above line to this:

```
This is some [example][1] line of text.

[1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Since the file is rather large and contains many *inline* links, I was wondering if there is some automated way to do this. I use Sublime Text 3 to edit, but I couldn't find a suitable package for this task. Perhaps some clever regex?

Comment: Do you expect the "tool" to combine multiple occurrences of the the same URL to the same reference number?

Comment: @reto well it wouldn't hurt, but I'd be willing to fix these instances myself if that's as good as it gets.

Comment: Does Sublime Text 3 come with a script or macro language of its own, or does it have an interface with an external language such as Perl, Python, Javascript or Visual Basic for Applications?

Comment: @Jongware as far as I can tell Sublime 3 supports regex and that's it. I don't think it has a script language of its own, at least none that I'm aware of. I think you might be the first SO user I've come across with such a high rep that isn't familiar with Sublime Text. Are you a vi/emacs user?

Comment: I'm firmly wedded to GUIs. On Windows I use TextPad, on Mac TextWrangler. While neither provide a (very good) scripting language, they can both run console programs and capture its output, so I would go ahead and write a custom tool in C, just for this. The required level of storing/counting/retrieving is beyond what GREP can (and should) do.

Comment: @Gabriel: I might give Sublime a test run. FYI only: it *does* directly support one of the more powerful languages: [Python](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a great requirement!

I've just created a new Node.js program (I know it's not a GUI but seems something more people would like the capability of) to do this on [GitHub](https://github.com/bjfletcher/convert-markdown-inlined-links-to-references).

Here's also the code:

```
// node main.js test.md result.md

var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], 'utf8', function (err, markdown) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    var counter = 1;
    var matches = {};
    var matcher = /\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/g;
    while (match = matcher.exec(markdown)) {
        if (!matches[match[1]]) matches[match[1]] = counter++;
    }
    console.log(matches);
    Object.keys(matches).forEach(function(url) {
        var r = new RegExp("(\\[.*?\\])\\(" + url + "\\)", "g");
        markdown = markdown.replace(r, "$1[" + matches[url] + "]");
        markdown += "\n[" + matches[url] + "]: " + url;
    });

    fs.writeFile(process.argv[3], markdown, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you add option to format the number (Like having 3 leading zeros, etc...)? Will it handle the same links to have the same reference number? Actually StackOverflow editor does it very well.

Answer (score 5):

Save this as `mdrelink.py` in your Packages folder, and you can then run it with

```
view.run_command('mdrelink');
```

from within the command console.

I *think* I got the order thingy right – reversing is necessary because otherwise it would mess up the already cached indexes of next items. It should also automatically skip already used link numbers. My first Python *and* my first Sublime plugin, so please be gentle with me.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class mdrelinkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        oldlinks = []
        self.view.find_all("^\s*(\[\d+\]):", sublime.IGNORECASE, "\\1", oldlinks)
        newlinkpos = self.view.find_all("\[.+?\](\(.+?\))")
        orgtext = []
        self.view.find_all("(\[.+?\])\(.+?\)", sublime.IGNORECASE, "\\1", orgtext)
        orglink = []
        self.view.find_all("\[.+?\]\((.+?)\)", sublime.IGNORECASE, "\\1", orglink)
        orglink.reverse()
        self.view.insert(edit, self.view.size(), '\n\n')
        counter = 1
        newnumbers = []
        for r in newlinkpos:
            while '['+str(counter)+']' in oldlinks:
                 counter += 1
            oldlinks.append('['+str(counter)+']')
            line = '[' + str(counter)+']: '+ orglink.pop() + '\n'
            newnumbers.append('  ['+str(counter)+']')
            self.view.insert(edit, self.view.size(), line)
        for r in reversed(newlinkpos):
            self.view.replace(edit, r, orgtext.pop()+newnumbers.pop())
```

Comment: And it only took you a couple of hours from not using Sublime to writing a plugin for it :) You should consider uploading this to https://packagecontrol.io/ which is where all Sublime packages live and can be easily installed via the Package Manager. I'll give this one a try as soon as I can. Thank you Jongware!

Comment: Has anyone made it work? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Came across this question thanks to Google. Maybe this can help others:

My answer isn't Sublime specific, but if you're using JavaScript (Node) already, I'd use a Markdown parser and CST transformer like [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark).

For example, to transform all the inline links in `README.md` to [numerically-ascending reference-style links](https://github.com/Xunnamius/unified-utils/tree/main/packages/remark-renumber-references), you could run the following at your project's root:

```bash
npm install --save-dev remark-cli remark-renumber-references
npx remark --no-stdout --output --use renumber-references README.md
```

Or, if you want [reference-style links derived from the source uri](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-defsplit):

```bash
npm install --save-dev remark-cli remark-defsplit
npx remark --no-stdout --output --use defsplit README.md
```

Hopefully this info helps people like me not waste a whole day hacking together some horrendously unreliable regexp-based solution to this :)

Comment: I'm getting an error `Could not find module 'reference-links'`

Comment: @Gangula might be the global install flag (`-g`). Try `npm install --no-save remark-reference-links remark-cli` (perhaps without `--no-save`) followed by `npx remark README.md -o --use reference-links` at your repo's root directory, assuming you're trying to mutate a file called `README.md`. Actually, I think I'll update the answer and remove sudo/globals.

Comment: it works now. Although I suggest `npm install --save-dev remark-reference-links remark-cli`, since in this case, these are not production dependencies.

Comment: Good idea. Updated!

Comment: if I used `remark-reference-links` on an existing markdown, the existing numbers don't get updated. I would like the reference links to be reset - starting from 1. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Gangula I'm actually working on a version of remark-reference-links (I'll call it remark-renumber-references) that will do just this, though I'm busy with other projects. In the meantime, try passing over the document twice: once with remark-inline-links (which is the inverse transform of remark-reference-links) and then again with remark-reference-links. This will restart numbering at 1 with references numbered in the order that they appear in the document. This will cause ALL references to be renumbered though, not just numbered references, something remark-renumber-references will solve.

Comment: @Gangula [remark-renumber-references](https://npm.im/remark-renumber-references) is live :)

Comment: This is really great @Xunnamius, can you add this as a separate answer to this question? I have a couple of questions, which would be better suited in that answer - for example (how to ignore links to headings from same document, etc...)

Comment: @Gangula I think it'd be easier to move discussions about the package to [GitHub](https://github.com/Xunnamius/unified-utils/discussions) :)

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. But regardless, it would be helpful for the users coming to this page, if you mention you package in an answer.

Comment: Agreed. I updated the answer a little while ago :)

Answer (score 0):

extending [@bjfletcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919298/6908282), below is the code that considers any existing reference links.
Link to [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/AnweshGangula/e42d1fd3e85e9d00bd613e7b28bcc2b9).

```js
// command to run
// node filename.js ReadMe.md RefLinks.md

import * as fs from 'fs'
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], 'utf8', function (err, mainMarkdown) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    let newMarkdown = existingRefLinks(mainMarkdown);

    var counter = 1;
    var matches = {};
    var matcher = /\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/g
    let match;
    while (match = matcher.exec(newMarkdown)) {
        if (!matches[match[1]]) matches[match[1]] = counter++;
    }
    console.log(matches);
    Object.keys(matches).forEach(function (url) {
        var r = new RegExp("(\\[.*?\\])\\(" + url + "\\)", "g");
        newMarkdown = newMarkdown.replace(r, "$1[" + matches[url] + "]");
        newMarkdown += "\n[" + matches[url] + "]: " + url;
    });

    fs.writeFile(process.argv[3], newMarkdown, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });

});

function existingRefLinks(markdown) {
    let refLinks = {}, match;
    const matcher = /\[(\d)]:\s(.*)/g; // /\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/g
    while (match = matcher.exec(markdown)) {
        if (!refLinks[match[1]]) refLinks[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    markdown = markdown.replaceAll(matcher, "")

    Object.keys(refLinks).forEach(function (int) {
        markdown = markdown.replace("][" + int + "]", "](" + refLinks[int] + ")");
    });
    return markdown
}
```

---

Note that I prefer using  [@Xunnamius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526897/6908282):

```bash
npm install --save-dev remark-reference-links remark-cli
npx remark README.md -o --use reference-links
```

Comment: Although I prefer [@Xunnamius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526897/6908282) to use `npm install --save-dev remark-reference-links remark-cli` since it uses remark which is more reliable and handles multiple other scenarios.