# JS Regex - replace contents of markdown link

Tags: javascript, regex

I've almost got a regex question figured out, just one little thing.

I am trying to get this:

`and so use [chalk](#api).red(string[, options])`

Into this:

`and so use chalk.red(string[, options])`

I have this:

```
var md = 'and so use chalk.red(string[, options])';
console.log(md.replace(/(\[.*?\]\()(.+?)(\))/g, '$1'))
```

Which matches the `[x](y)` perfectly. However, `$1` returns `[chalk](`. I would like it to return `chalk` instead, and I'm stumped on how to do this.

#### I might(?) have figured it out:

Does this do the trick in all cases?

```
/(\[(.*?)\]\()(.+?)(\))/g
```

Comment: I'm confused, your before and after strings are identical

Comment: Whoops you were right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917399/convert-markdown-links-from-inline-to-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at what your current regex does

```
/(\[(.*?)\]\()(.+?)(\))/g
1st Capturing group (\[(.*?)\]\()
    \[ matches the character [ literally
    2nd Capturing group (.*?)
        .*? matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    \] matches the character ] literally
    \( matches the character ( literally
3rd Capturing group (.+?)
    .+? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
4th Capturing group (\))
    \) matches the character ) literally
```

As you can see your 1st capture group contains your 2nd capture group. The 2nd capture group is `chalk` and your first is `[chalk](`.

1. You could change your javascript to read `console.log(md.replace(/(\[.*?\]\()(.+?)(\))/g, '$2'))`
2. rewrite your regex to remove the parenthesis that capture the brackets so your only capturing whats inside them. `\[(.*?)\]\((.+?)\)`

If your new to regular expressions I would highly recommend a regex tool such as regex101.com to see what your groups are and what exactly your regex is doing.

Heres your regex I saved for you
https://regex101.com/r/tZ6yK9/1

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegExp:

```
/\[([^\]]+)\][^\)]+\)/g
```

and if you call this

```
'and so use [chalk](#api).red(string[, options])'.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\][^\)]+\)/g, '$1')
```

it returns this

> "and so use chalk.red(string[, options])"