# Regex match markdown link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with markdown in it. I am trying to strip all markdown using regex but am having trouble with matching links. Here's how far I got:

```
function stripMarkdown(text) {
  var str = String(text).replace(/(__|\*|\#)/gm, '');
  return str;
}

var testStr = '# This is the title. ## This is the subtitle. **some text** __some more text__. [link here](http://google.com)'

stripMarkdown(testStr);
```

So I believe the above will strip all unwanted markdown except the link. How do I handle that? Also, if there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Desired outcome:

```
This is the title. This is the subtitle. some text some more text. link here
```

Comment: Would this do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381742/js-regex-replace-contents-of-markdown-link ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I came up with this regex:

```
(?:__|[*#])|\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)
```

```js
var str = '# This is the title. ## This is the subtitle. **some text** __some more text__. [link here](http://google.com)'

document.write(String(str).replace(/(?:__|[*#])|\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/gm, '$1'));
```

Comment: This matches an empty link: `()[]`... desired behavior?

Comment: @BenPolinsky one can change it to `(?:__|[*#])|\[(.+?)\]\(.+?\)` if needed, but an empty link is style a link, isn't it? :p

Comment: This also seems to match markdown heading tags `##` and bold tags `**`.

Comment: I'd add a second group for the link: `(?:__|[*#])|\[(.+?)]\((.+?)\)`

Comment: It matches the literal `#`. and `*` which are in no way a markdown link

Comment: This matches images too, which have `![abc](def)` notation

Comment: @zed you're right. You can add a negative lookbehind if you're using V8+ JS

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer matches bold tags `*` and headings `###`. Marvin's fix matches weird groups of text if you have more than one bracket pair on a line. (e.g. `[word] a [link](url)`)

This regex fixes that:

```
.replace(/\[([^\[\]]*)\]\((.*?)\)/gm, '$1')
```

Note that URLs with bracket pairs in them will need to be URL encoded

Comment: This regex fail with `[aaaa[bbb]dd](some-url)`.

Answer (score 4):

Thomas's answer above can match headings with `###` and bold tags `*`. To avoid matching those use the following regex instead:

```
.replace(/([])|\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/gm, '$1')
```

Might be useful for those using javascript/node to match link pattern on markdown.

Answer (score 2):

For me, It's work

```
string.match(/\[[^\]]*\]\([^)]*\)*/)
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match markdown text following the `[some reference text](some url)` pattern - and includes two groups containing the values of both the reference text and the url.

`\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)`

If you want, you can just simply replace the markdown text with reference text in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is far too complex to do this properly with a simple regular expression. Consider the following examples:

```markdown
[`[test](test)`](test)
[\[](test) [\]](test)
`[test` [test](test) `test](test)`
``test`[test`` [test](test) ``test`](test)``
```

In Markdown, characters have a different meaning depending in which context they appear. As you can see, even the syntax highlighting of StackOverflow has trouble to interpret the last line correctly. In addition, Markdown compilers often allow raw HTML in the text.

If you want a simple solution, compile the Markdown and strip out all the HTML elements:

```js
function getMarkdownText(markdown) {
    const compiled = sanitize(marked(markdown));
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = compiled;
    return el.innerText;
}
```

If you want a solution that runs faster but is more complex to implement, hook into a markdown compiler yourself and make it generate the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function stripMarkdown(text) {
  var str = String(text).replace(/__|\*|\#|(?:\[([^\]]*)\]\([^)]*\))/gm, '$1');
  return str;
}

var testStr = '# This is the title. ## This is the subtitle. **some text** __some more text__. [link here](http://google.com)'

document.write(stripMarkdown(testStr));
```

It replaces the match with the first capture group, which is the link's text. If the match is something other than the link (markdown) this is empty.