# In VS Code, when editing markdown, is there a way to automatically convert all links and bare URLs to reference links?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

While editing markdown files with VS Code, I would like to be able to automatically convert all links and bare URL in given document to [reference links](https://markdownguide.offshoot.io/basic-syntax/#reference-style-links). As a nice-to-have all the reference link definitions should be moved to the end of the file and sorted alphabetically.

The closest I found is the [Extract to link definition for Markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_extract-to-link-definition-for-markdown) and [Organize link definitions in Markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_organize-link-definitions-in-markdown) features.

However, it doesn't do exactly what I need. I am looking for a command that given following markdown file:

```markdown
paragraph 1

[foo](https://example.com)

paragraph 2

https://example.org

paragraph 3

[baz][qux]

paragraph 4
```

upon executing the command, will convert the file to:

```markdown
paragraph 1

[foo]

paragraph 2

[TODO1]

paragraph 3

[baz][qux]

paragraph 4

[foo]: https://example.com
[qux]: TODO2
[TODO1]: https://example.org
```

The expectation here is that as the user I will manually replace `TODO1` and `TODO2` with appropriate values and re-run the command to re-sort the reference links.

Related question:

- [Convert markdown links from inline to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917399/convert-markdown-links-from-inline-to-reference)